# How can I slide up this menu after I click a page?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and when I click one of the menu titles it is going to my page but the menu is not sliding up, it is still open until I click the hamburger

```
var $window = $(window);
var gsnavfixH = $('#gs-navfix').outerHeight();


var GSnavFix = function(){
    $window.on('load', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var mainFirstChildHeight = $('main>header').outerHeight();

        if ($window.scrollTop() >= mainFirstChildHeight - gsnavfixH)
            $('#gs-navfix').addClass('gs-appear');
        else
            $('#gs-navfix').removeClass('gs-appear');
    });
};

GSnavFix();

var GSnavRight = function(){

    $('.gs-hamburger').on('click', function(event) {

      console.log('yghygygyg', $('.gs-hamburger'));
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.gs-hamburger').toggleClass('gs-close');
        $('#gs-nav-static-hamburger').toggleClass('gs-nav-right-appear');
        $('main,#gs-navfix,#gs-nav-static').toggleClass('gs-nav-right-appear');
        $('#gs-nav-right').toggleClass('gs-appear');
    });


};

GSnavRight();
```

Comment: can you please provide a working example (e.g. a jsFiddle)? and pls add a bit of your html- and css-code, so it's easier for us to help you

Comment: is there any chance to use a plugin on jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes you can add external resources to your fiddle

Comment: well this is what I have. I don't know why is not working the js there but this is what I use for this http://jsfiddle.net/fze4nLL8/

Comment: http://iconiadev.com/menu/ this is how its working you can have a look on files if you give an inspect element from chrome and sources tab